# Unable to load DLL python module in PyCharm. Works fine in IPython

Tags: python, import, numpy, ipython, pycharm

When I use the IPython included with Enthought Python Distribution, I can import the pyvision package just fine. However, when I try to import pyvision inside of PyCharm 1.2.1, I get the following errors

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvision\__init__.py", line 146, in <module>
    from pyvision.types.img import Image,OpenCVToNumpy,NumpyToOpenCV
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvision\types\img.py", line 43, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Am I missing some path settings in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I'm using Winpython32 and trying to `import win32com`. Worked everywhere (I tried) except in PyCharm. `sys.path` and `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` had some extra entries inside Pycharm, but nothing is missing compared to when run elsewhere.

The solution was to start Pycharm within the Winpython console and not using the shortcut.

`sys.path` and `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` did not change. `os.environ['PATH']` had several additional entries set, all related to the python installation. At this point I suspect it has to do with "non-standard" installations. Winpython32 tries to be "portable", while other reports of similar problems are when using Enthought or Python(x,y).

Manually adding:

```
 C:\WinPython-32\python-2.7.6\
 C:\WinPython-32\python-2.7.6\DLLs
 C:\WinPython-32\python-2.7.6\Scripts
```

to the system path (the global PATH environment variable in Windows) solved the problem without having to run Pycharm within the Winpython command line. Note: `C:\WinPython-32\python-2.7.6\Scripts` alone did not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem before, and it seemed to get fixed by repairing Enthought.

EDIT: I just checked, one of my f2py projects was still suffering from this exact error. Repairing Enthought did not work. The solution to my problem actually lay in fixing the Windows path variable. You need to make sure c:\Python27\Scripts (or your equivalent) is in the path. Furthermore, and this is VERY important, make sure each entry in the global and user path environment variables has NO trailing slashes. This breaks the GNU make utility on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your PATH environment variable

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty frustrating bug in PyCharm. Even if you set your virtualenv from within PyCharm, the "python console" defaults to the system python. When you installed PyCharm, presumably you used a win32 python on a 64 bit machine.

Go to `file>settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Console>Python Console` and change the `Python Interpreter` from the system version to your virtualenv.

Of course, PyCharm doesn't immediately refresh it. You have to close your project and reopen it.

To verify this was successful, open the Python Console (`Tools>Python Console`) and check the very first line of the output: it should point to the `python.exe` of your virtual environment, not the system python.

Comment: Same sadly, it points to the correct python interpreter, but there is a mismatch between what I get from simply running python from the terminal vs what I get in Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (with another package) and I don't want to modify windows path.
I could solve it very roughly in the pycharm console, by creating a python script which updates sys.path and os.environ['PATH'] in file -settings-console-pathon console - starting script.It works only when I use "tools- python shell"

Still it doesn't work in the run options. I even tried to create a virtual environment, add the path to the activate.bat but in pycharm it doesn't work (from command prompt it does) (as suggested in [virtualenv that can find relocated libraires (like mysqlclient lib for MySQLdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771204/virtualenv-that-can-find-relocated-libraires-like-mysqlclient-lib-for-mysqldb) )
I explicilty set the path in the python interpreter option but it doesn't work.(as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206781/1136458)

Answer (score 0):

[image] I couldn't find the link but I saved this pic - hopefully works for you

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my explanation being long and probably not the best of clarity, but this is the best I could do to describe my experience.

I was having the same problem after first installation and this is how I solved it:

I had noticed there are some settings, as indicated in other answers, that tell pyCharm which interpreters and environment managers to use and I was sure the problem was with setting these options, but I was not sure how, so I started searching.

#### Setting interpreter

I had more or less followed the standard tutorial, assuming in some point I would have used newly created virtualenv inside my project folder. I was initially getting the DLL error, but as I made sure the `interpreter` settings were pointing at a valid executable.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) it is explained how to do this.

#### Setting environment

at this point the error disappeared, but I had progressed towards a new error.
The problem at this point I was not being able to import any module as they were not found.
This is because I was working inside the newly created virtualenv, basically a pristine installation, with no modules installed. I am sure there are more evolved solutions (install modules in the virtualenv), but I was just looking for making the code to work, so I set the environment to use my anaconda usual development environment.

For me, with conda on windows (after activating the development environment with `conda activate`) then (see [..../anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored) for other systems).
`where python` gives the path to the interpreter
`conda info --envs` gives me the existing environment that I want to use.

This fixed everything for me.