# Where should I search for the installed R packages by conda?

Tags: r, conda

I am installing r packages using conda. It works fine when I use this example format

> "conda install -c r r-scales --name condaenv"

But when I want to define installtion directory using --prefix

> conda install -c r r-scales --prefix=/opt/local

the package "scale" is installed but I cannot find it in the directory I expect to be

> "/opt/local/lib/R/library"

. It is weird because when I try to reinstall this package it says

> All requested packages already installed.

that means this package is already installed in defined path. **BUT WHERE?**
I also try using

> conda list

But I cannot find "scales" among installed packages.
**UPDATE:**
I also tried to use install.packages("scales), but I ran into this error

> /opt/anaconda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lm
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [/raid60/raid2/opt/local/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: scales.so] Error
>   1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ?scales?
>   * removing ?/raid60/raid2/opt/local/lib/R/library/scales?

Comment: Why not just installing R as is without conda?

Comment: Because I have consistently got an error, not only for this package but for many others. I also asked admin to fix it but he did not manage to. That is the error /opt/anaconda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/raid60/raid2/opt/local/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: scales.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ?scales?
* removing ?/raid60/raid2/opt/local/lib/R/library/scales?

Comment: That's an conda error. I'm asking why using conda in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, is not it your question "why did not you use  install.packages("scales)?" I did, but I got that error.

Comment: Yes, this is what happens when you install conda- it takes over your environment variables and makes you completely depended on it. It is worse than a virus. If I were you, I would uninstall conda and just install R without it.

Answer (score 0):

When using environments in conda, the r packages are installed inside the environment folder.

For instance, in Linux, if you have a environment `condaenv`, the R packages installed with conda (or its faster cousin [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) should be located at:

```
~/conda/envs/condaenv/lib/R/library/
```

to locate the environment folder in your system you can look at the answers provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored).