# Conda: list all environments that use a certain package

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

How can one get a list of all environments that use a certain package in conda?

Comment: Note that you can also do `conda list -n <envName>` instead of activating the environment first

Comment: Thanks, that is not a full solution but it is handy and easy to memorize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### conda search

Since Conda v 4.5.0, the `conda search` command has had an `--envs` flag for searching local environments for installed packages. See `conda search -h`:

```
--envs       Search all of the current user's environments. If run
             as Administrator (on Windows) or UID 0 (on unix),
             search all known environments on the system.
```

A use case given in [the original Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6791) was finding environments with outdated versions of `openssl` packages:

```
conda search --envs 'openssl<1.1.1l'
```

---

### Conda Python API

Here's an example of how to do it with the Conda Python package (run this in **base** environment):

```python
import conda.gateways.logging
from conda.core.envs_manager import list_all_known_prefixes
from conda.cli.main_list import list_packages
from conda.common.compat import text_type

# package to search for; this can be a regex
PKG_REGEX = "pymc3"

for prefix in list_all_known_prefixes():
    exitcode, output = list_packages(prefix, PKG_REGEX)
    
    # only print envs with results
    if exitcode == 0 and len(output) > 3:
        print('\n'.join(map(text_type, output)))
```

This works as of Conda v4.10.0, but there since it relies on internal methods, there's no guarantee going forward. Perhaps this should be a feature request, say for a CLI command like `conda list --any`.

---

#### Script Version

Here is a version that uses arguments for package names:

**conda-list-any.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n base --no-capture-output python

## Usage: conda-list-any.py [PACKAGE ...]
## Example: conda-list-any.py numpy pandas

import conda.gateways.logging
from conda.core.envs_manager import list_all_known_prefixes
from conda.cli.main_list import list_packages
from conda.common.compat import text_type
import sys


for pkg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print("#"*80)
    print("# Checking for package '%s'..." % pkg)

    n = 0
    for prefix in list_all_known_prefixes():
        exitcode, output = list_packages(prefix, pkg)
        if exitcode == 0 and len(output) > 3:
            n += 1
            print("\n" + "\n".join(map(text_type, output)))

    print("\n# Found %d environment%s with '%s'." % (n, "" if n == 1 else "s", pkg))
    print("#"*80 + "\n")
```

The shebang at the top should ensure that it will run in **base**, at least on Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: As there isn't a conda command, this is the best solution I have seen. I have just added the package name as a command line argument and it works great.

Comment: @tiagoams turns out there was a CLI option this whole time! (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue and constructed a Powershell script that:

- takes a regex query as an argument
- goes through all available conda environments (and shows a progress bar while doing so)
- lists all packages in each environment
- returns the environments that have a package that match the query
- per returned environment shows the package name that matched the query

The script is available at the bottom of this answer. I have saved it in a folder that is avaialble in the PATH under the name `search-pkg-env.ps1`.

The script can be run as follows (here I search for environments with the `pip` package [`pymupdf`](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/)):

```powershell
PS > search-pkg-env.ps1 pymupdf
Searching 19 conda environments...
py39
 - pymupdf 1.18.13
```

#### Script

```powershell
if ($args.Length -eq 0) {
  Write-Host "Please specify a search term for that matches the package name (regex)." -BackgroundColor DarkYellow -ForegroundColor White
    exit
}

$pkg_regex = $args[0]
$conda_envs = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $([string]$(conda env list --json))

$total = $conda_envs.envs.Count
Write-Host "Searching $total conda environments..."
$counter = 1

ForEach ($conda_env in $conda_envs.envs) {
  if ($total -gt 0) {
      $progress = $counter / $total * 100
  }
  else {
      $progress = 0
  }
  # Split the full path into its elements
  $parts = $conda_env -Split '\\'
  # The last element has the env name
  $env_name = $parts[-1]
  Write-Progress -Activity "Searching conda environment $env_name for $pkg_regex" -PercentComplete $progress
  # Now search the provided package name in this environment
  $search_results = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $([string]$(conda list $pkg_regex -n $env_name --json))
  If ($search_results.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host $env_name
      foreach ($result in $search_results) {
        $pkg_name = $result.name
        $pkg_version = $result.version
        Write-Host " - $pkg_name $pkg_version"
      }
  }
  $counter++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python + Terminal solution

#### Jump directly to solution:

Use the following Github script [Listing Environments Containing a Set of Packages](https://github.com/mohamadmansourX/random-utilities#listing-environments-containing-set-of-packages)

***You Don't Need to install any Library***

Simply copy the script, run and provide the set of packages needed (one or more)

---

#### From Scratch Solution:

To find all environments that contains a set of packages (one or more):

1. Get all the conda environments using Popen and `conda env list`; this will list all conda envs on your station.
2. Loop over the packages and check if a package exist in a conda env using Popen and `conda list -n <environment>`; this will list all available packages in an environment
3. Check through the output if it exists using either `grep`, `findstr` or your platform alternative on the terminal output - or do the search with python.
4. For each package save in a list
5. Check through lists for common environments and Voila!