# How to uninstall nodejs with conda or pip?

Tags: node.js, pip, conda

I tried `conda remove nodejs` and `pip uninstall nodejs` but it doesn't work. I get this error message `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment: - nodejs`

but when I use conda search nodejs. It turns out the package still exists.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conda search` command does not give information about local installations, but instead queries Anaconda Cloud to see what packages are *available* to install.

To check what is installed, use the `conda list` command. If you wish to check every environment for a given package, see [Conda: list all environments that use a certain package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59752323/570918).

Comment: Yeah you're right [conda cheetshet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) mislead me about `conda search`