# conda 4.8.3 cannot install packages, make new envs, or update

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I try to download a library, create an env or even pdate but every time I do it seems like anaconda doesn't respond:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>conda create --name truc_env python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>
```

And whether it's in the pycharm or anaconda terminal...

I can activate an environment but not install libraries:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi>conda activate mod_env

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>
```

## Difference with sahasrara62's link

I am not installing a Virtualenvs plugin for SublimeText 3 and I'm not asked for virtualenvs path. I am trying to download a library.

Nevertheless here are the results prompted with the queries of the most upvoted question:

```
(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>echo %CONDA_PREFIX%
C:\Users\antoi\.conda\envs\mod_env

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>where python
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

## Update

I tried to add it in the path as I thought I was using Anaconda 3 and as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35717840/4764604) but it didn't worked

```
(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I verified the version of Anaconda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And now I guess I have a version problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda Python: where are the virtual environments stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored)

Comment: Could you please provide a more descriptive title?

Comment: When you create the env, you name it `env_cvxopt `, but later you activate `mod_env`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thanks for the link, unforunately not. I've updated my question to show why.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen Thanks for noticing. Just some leftovers of another attempt. I've updated