# Error when trying to install autodocking Vina

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install Autodock Vina with pip command. But when I run the command `pip install -U numpy vina:` I get a the following error:

```
Collecting vina
  Using cached vina-1.2.3.tar.gz (95 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [52 lines of output]
      Version found 1.2.3 (from __init__.py)
      running egg_info
      writing vina.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to vina.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to vina.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to vina.egg-info\top_level.txt
      Boost library is not installed in this conda environment.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 346, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 299, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 541, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 578, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
          build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
        File "C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-km4q58s5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
          self.finalize_options()
        File "setup.py", line 247, in finalize_options
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: Boost library location was not found!
      Directories searched: conda env, /usr/local/include and /usr/include.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and fixed it by installing `boost` and `swig` libraries. Unfortunately, I do not completely know how to do that on Windows, but the rough sketch of what you should do is:

1. Locate your active `conda` environment. If there are none, create and activate one before installing your project dependencies. To get to know the location of your environment, use `conda info`. For more, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored) stackoverflow thread.
2. Download [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) and [swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Windows.html) as archives from these links to their official website.
3. Unpack the archives into the conda environment folder.
4. Try installing again (make sure you have activated the environment) `pip install -U numpy vina`.

For the Linux and MacOS users that may have the same issue, the solution is very similar, except that you do not have to activate a conda environment. Instead, you can install `boost` and `swig` globally in your system, as described in [this](https://autodock-vina.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-from-source) guide in the autodock-vina website.

1. Install C++ compiler.

Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`

macOS: Install Xcode from the AppStore and the Command Line Tools (CLT) from the terminal `xcode-select --install`

2. Install `boost` and `swig` in your system

Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev swig`

macOS (with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)): `brew install boost swig`