# How to retrieve the path of a conda package?

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I would like to change the content of a file of the tensorflow library used in one of my conda environment.

I tried to detect where the tensorflow library is located, but the only thing I know is to use:

```
conda list
```

which notably reveals the version of tensorflow:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

But that's it...

So,  my question is: how do I retrieve the path of tensorflow here ? (I am using Linux)

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda Python: where are the virtual environments stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored)

Comment: See duplicate. However, note that editing Tensorflow is not trivial. Maybe take time to read up on developer docs on [the repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).