# How can I use existing user-local conda virtual enviroment with intelliji IDEA?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, anaconda

I want to configure intelliji idea to use conda virtual enviroment I created beforehand. This enviroment is located at `C:\\Users\<username>\.conda\env` which I found by running `conda activate <envname> && echo %conda_prefix%` as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709497/anaconda-python-where-are-the-virtual-environments-stored).

I created a new intelliji idea project, and then navigated to project structure, then SDK under project. I expected to see the name of the enviroment as one of the options together with other conda enviroments (global, stored at `C:\\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\`) but it was not there. Moreover, when I inspected the contents of the new env directory it has just a single subdirectory called `conda-meta` with a history file inside. While enviroment directories in the anaconda3 directory has all stuff you would expect it ti have including the interpreter.

Now, is it a different kind of enviroment? How do I use it in intelliji IDEA?

Comment: Try creating a new conda environment using `conda create -n my_env python=3.12`, substitute the env name and python version with your own. This should create a proper env with a separate python executable.